# Error using SignalR utility Crank.exe

Tags: signalr, load-testing

I'm using crank to load test my signalr application. The command that I'm using is as follows

```
crank /NumClients:100 /Url:http://localhost:29573/TestConnection /BatchSize:10
```

I'm getting an exception in my powershell window as follows...

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object
reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.GetUrl(String url, Boolean useDefaultUrl) in c:\Users\t-niraj\Deskto
p\SignalR-master\src\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client\HubConnection.cs:line 216
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection..ctor(String url, Boolean useDefaultUrl) in c:\Users\t-niraj\Desktop
\SignalR-master\src\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client\HubConnection.cs:line 38
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection..ctor(String url) in c:\Users\t-niraj\Desktop\SignalR-master\src\Mic
rosoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client\HubConnection.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank.Client.<OpenControllerConnection>d__6.MoveNext() in c:\Users\t-niraj\Desktop\Signal
R-master\src\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank\Client.cs:line 71
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank.Client.<Run>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\t-niraj\Desktop\SignalR-master\src\Microsof
t.AspNet.SignalR.Crank\Client.cs:line 43
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank.Client.Main() in c:\Users\t-niraj\Desktop\SignalR-master\src\Microsoft.AspNet.Signa
lR.Crank\Client.cs:line 34
```

I do have the sample application: SignalR.LoadTestHarness running at localhost:29573. This is the same application that is found in the SignalR source code samples.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide the `ControllerUrl` parameter and as a result crank is [trying to create a hub connection with null Url](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank/Client.cs#L71) which results in throwing a `NullReferenceException` on [this](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/HubConnection.cs#L216) line.